# Reg Ex to remove "# " from "# 9NE832"

Tags: regex

I have a string that includes "# 9NE832" and i wand to remove "# " so just "9NE832" is left. That number will change though so i need to be able to remove the pound sign and space.

I've tried this "[a-zA-Z0-9]+" but it's not working. Any help would be much appreciated.

Also if anyone knows of a site where you can input the string and input how you want it to look. and have the regex spit out, please share!

Comment: Why do you need a regex? Just do a string replacement of `"# "` with an empty string.

Comment: What language are you using?

Comment: I don't think a site like you describe exists. There's no way to figure out the general pattern from a single example.

Comment: regex is a pattern matching system, it has variants based on languages, replacing things based on regex is dependent on the language.  Without knowing that we can't really answer it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

About a site where you can input the string and input how you want it to look, I never heard of.

But you regex case is fairly simple, you can use this simple regex: `#\s*(.*)`

This will capture `(.*)` everything coming after a `#` and 0 or more spaces `\s*`.